# Tutorial for using TriggerIO with impactJS?

Tags: trigger.io

Has anyone tried this? Is there a tutorial out there for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although I don't know of anyone using Impact with Trigger.io, anything which works in a standard browser should work just fine as a Trigger Forge app.

I've tried their [Drop demo](http://impactjs.com/drop/) in the stock Android and iPhone browsers and it works fine: should be fine as a Forge app too!